# Network fails to configure on boot

Tags: boot, networking

Ubuntu server 64bit 14.04.2

On boot it waits for network configuration then says waiting 60 more seconds.
I cant ping gateway or internet.

`ifconfig` shows only lo

`ifconfig -a` shows eth0 and lo

I manually configured `/etc/network/interfaces` to static

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.10.10
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.10.0
broadcast 192.168.10.255
gateway 192.168.10.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
```

`route -n` does not show gateway all values return blank

It worked last night as of today its awesome sauce.

This is on a vbox with the NIC bridged

I have also tried

```
sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
sudo dhclient
```

Comment: I just ran sudo ip link set dev eth0 up now I can see the eth0 in ifconfig showing no inet address

Comment: Whats the IP of the host machine?

Comment: The vbox? should I use that for the gateway? 192.168.10.108

Comment: I made another VM Server. It is an issue with how I am setting up the static IP. I have looked at 3 examples and followed them exactly I don't understand what I am doing wrong.

Comment: There are two `netmask` lines in `/etc/network/interfaces`..remove any one..then run `sudo ifdown eth0 && sudo ifup -v eth0`..

Comment: There are two netmask lines in /etc/network/interfaces..remove any one..then run sudo ifdown eth0 && sudo ifup -v eth0..        –  heemayl      This followed by sudo dhclient did the trick. Thanks lots!

Comment: Glad it solved the issue..i am gonna put this as an answer (please accept that as the answer) so that future readers can take help from this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `/etc/network/interfaces` file you have duplicate lines of the following:

```
netmask 255.255.255.0
```

Remove the duplicates keeping just one. As you are using Virtualbox adapter in Bridged mode everything else seems fine.

Now run the following to bring the `eth0` interface down and then up to make the changes take place instantly:

```
sudo ifdown eth0 && sudo ifup -v eth0
```